# Get RSS from LINEST in one cell

Tags: excel

I need to return the RSS from a regression in one cell.

To get the slope I use `=INDEX(LINEST(C28:C43,B28:B43),1)`
To get the y-intercept I use `=INDEX(LINEST(C28:C43,B28:B43),2)`
Is there an easy way like this to get RSS?

Comment: By RSS, do you mean residual sum of squares?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track.  To get the residual sum of squares, you have to refer to the second column of the LINEST results array:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(C28:C43,B28:B43),5,2)
```

If you want the regression sum of squares instead, use this:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(C28:C43,B28:B43),5,1)
```